# ion-infinite-scroll not firing ionInfinite event - Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to use infinite scroll with a simple code to test. The issue is `ion-infinite-scroll` no longer firing `ionInfinite` event.

Below is my code and `ionic info` of my project.

`home.ts`

```
listData=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"];
fiveobjects = [];
page = 0;
maximumPages = 3;

constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
this.get_data_from_array(event);
}

...

async get_data_from_array(event){
 this.fiveobjects =  this.listData.slice(0, 10);
 console.log(this.fiveobjects);

 if(event){
   event.target.complete();
 }
}

loadMore(event){
  console.log(event);
this.page++;
this.get_data_from_array(event);

if(this.page === this.maximumPages){
  event.target.disabled = true;
}
}

}
```

`home.html`

```
<ion-content>
<ion-card>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of fiveobjects">
    <ion-label>{{item}}</ion-label>   
  <br>
    <ion-label>..</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>

<ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadMore($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
  </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

**Ionic info**

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (C:\Users\saurabh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.5    
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v12.14.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Should be firing the event, the only issue I can see is that this might be causing strange behaviour this.fiveobjects =  this.listData.slice(0, 10); it just sets the result array to the same 10 strings each time so it may look like nothing is happening

Comment: Also remember a scroll event needs to happen to fire the event, if your initial data is not long enough to exceed the screen height no event will fire.

Comment: yes it worked fine, dont know i just closed the entire project and browser, then did ionic serve and boom, all started working fine

Comment: new problem - it is only getting called once, 2nd time it is not getting called

Comment: @user2828442 - Did you find any solution for this. I am facing same issues as yours.